# Assign uploaded photos to Post after Post is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, ckeditor

Let's say I'm on `/posts/new` where is also photo upload feature (asynchronously, using [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)).

How to reference each uploaded photo to the post after post is saved? I mean setting `photo.post_id` (ok, in case of ckeditor gem it's `assetable_type` and `assetable_id`).

Do I have to do post.save in controller #new action? I hope there is better solution.

---

My controller code is just regular rails style:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build post_params
  if @post.save
    redirect_to [:admin, :posts]
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And form:

```
= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.cktext_area :body
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `posts/new`?

Comment: I've updated question with #new and #create actions, but nothing special there.

Comment: Can you post the form code as well?

Comment: Done, form code added.